# What evidence shows that Mr. Fuji is the same person as Dr. Fuji?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

A common fan theory about the generation 1 games is that Team Rocket's actions were all

> unified by the theme of trying to capture Mewtwo.

I cannot recall the details, but I recall that this theory hinges on Mr. Fuji and Dr. Fuji being the same person. What evidence supports this in the generation 1 games?

**Note:** I'm strictly concerned with evidence as it exists in the first generation games. I'm confident that some of the relevant signs, dialogues, and journals changed in the remakes.

In order to be certain that the information is from Gen 1, I strongly encourage answers to show pictures of the evidence that they're using. Any suspicion of translation issues should be backed up by the original Japanese.

I'd like to see the link between him and the unnamed author of the diaries. To be honest, I thought said author was named "Dr Fuji" even in Gen 1.

Comment: If you're referring purely to the generation one games, then you won't find anything about the character "Dr Fuji" at all - he's only seen in the anime. Is your question asking to link the character of Mr Fuji from the games with the character of Dr Fuji from the movie Mewtwo Strikes Back? Or do you purely want to stick to the games, and link the character of Mr Fuji with the unnamed author of the diaries in Cinnabar Mansion? (Or if you're happy to accept Pokémon Origins, then the link is made explicit.)

Comment: @Showsni Purely the games. I'd like to see the link between him and the unnamed author of the diaries. To be honest, I thought said author was named "Dr Fuji" even in gen 1.

Comment: The bulbapedia link about Mr Fuji has some hints, though not confirmation: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mr._Fuji. There are more hints if you count the non-generation 1 games, which makes it arguably confirmatory. As Showsni said, Pokemon Origins does make the link explicit, but it contrasts with Dr Fuji from the movies. Note, this is only about Mr Fuji and Dr Fuji, as opposed to the fan theory about Team Rocket (which I haven't heard of before).

Comment: Not really a "strict" to Gen 1, but the guidebook for Let's go Pikachu/Eevee (which is, remake of Gen 1) that was released in Japan confirms that Mr.Fuji and Dr.Fuji is a same man.